# Android orientation not perseved

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have one main activity in portrait mode, a sub activity in landscape mode.

Main calls startActivity to start the sub, and orientation is changed to landscape. It is correct.

Then at sub activity, press back button or call finish, it goes back to main. But this time, main activity is in landscape. It is not correct, main should restore to portrait.

My device is an android 5.0 nexus 7. I remember it worked for old Android OS, but somehow in the new OS, the issue appears.

Does anyone know it, and knows a fix Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Sure - If the issue is when you press the back button, you can make sure to set the orientation back to the correct state in the `onResume()` method - this should get called when you return to the previous activity.

So in your main activity - the one that you want to be in portrait mode - override the `onResume()` method, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's one solution. But I am curious why it used to work on old OS, but suddenly in Lollipop, it is no longer. Shouldn't Google publish it in release note and provides a API to backward support it.

Comment: @wtao I couldn't tell you why. People have been having small issues like this left and right. Yes, in an ideal world, Google should do that. I'm not sure why they haven't. This will certainly work, though.